# Existe alguma ferramenta para site fluido

Tags: layout-responsivo

alguém conhece alguma ferramenta que mostre o tamanho da tela? por exemplo conforme vou diminuindo o tamanho do navegador ela me mostre o tamanho da tela em `px` tinha uma no `github` mais acabei perdendo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo o próprio DevTools faz isso, basta apertar `F12` no Chrome e usar a ferramente de teste de devise clicando nesse icone ou apertando `ctrl+shift+m`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Além disso o Chrome tb tem uma serie de extensões para testar a responsividade direto no browser

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/responsive?hl=pt-BR

Eu uso essa https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mobileresponsive-web-desi/elmekokodcohlommfikpmojheggnbelo?hl=pt-BR

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]