# Como definir uma largura mínima para um layout com comportamento responsivo?

Tags: html, css, html5, mobile, layout-responsivo

Estou trabalhando num layout HTML "responsivo" cujos elementos internos se ajustam à largura da tela para desktop e dispositivos *mobile*. No entanto, não consigo estruturar meu layout de maneira funcional abaixo de **480px**. Sendo assim, gostaria de definir um comportamento responsivo até 480px e abaixo desta largura deixar que o celular use o recurso de *zoom out* automaticamente para ajustar o conteúdo à largura da tela **sem rolagem horizontal**, comportamento que costumamos observar ao carregar uma página não responsiva num navegador de celular.

Como deve ser minha *meta tag* **ViewPort**?

Quando uso...

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=480">
```

...ele perde a configuração e caso o usuário dê *zoom* ele salva esse estado e o *zoom* permanece mesmo ao recarregar a página, fazendo com que parte do conteúdo fique oculto e apresente barras de rolagem horizontal.

Se eu usar...

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=480, initial-scale=1">
```

...ele irá sempre carregar a página em 100%, apresentando sempre barras de rolagem horizontais em celulares com largura menor que 480px.

Além disso, me parece que em ambos os casos a página não consegue ser renderizada em telas maiores que 480px. Em alguns testes no iPhone pude perceber que ao aumentar a largura da tela (ao colocar o celular em modo *landscape*, por exemplo) ele exibe uma versão com *zoom in* da página renderizada em 480px, apenas.

Obs.: Alguma recomendação de ferramenta para testar o comportamento da *meta tag* **ViewPort** em diferentes celulares e resoluções?

Comment: Cada caso é um caso, mas a resposta arcada como duplicada ai tem detalhes que vão te ajudar. Mas aparentemente vc não deve usar initial-scale junto de um minimum-scale. Mas só vc testando com o seu documento para saber a ajustar. Não deixe de ler o link da documentação que citei lá https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: Já tinha lido as informações da pergunta que você mencionou, mas continuo sem encontrar uma solução. Você poderia, pelo menos, me recomendar uma ferramenta para fazer os testes que você sugeriu? Atualmente não consigo ter segurança de como o que defino para meu ViewPort resulta nos diferentes dispositivos e resoluções.

Comment: A melhor opção é usar o próprio DevTools para testar, ou então sincronizar seus arquivos com o GitHub e testar em outros dispositivos acessando a GitPage. Não recomendo ferramentas de test-online. O Chrome tb tem alguns plugins de Responsividade basta vc procurar. LEIA isso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/existe-alguma-ferramenta-para-site-fluido